# Nested model form Attributes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, scaffolding, form-for

I have a index page(simple scaffold generated listings) that list all ads. I have made so that when I click on a ad it will expand(css and jquery) and show the information on that ad. Now the problem that I cant get to work is that I want to be able to book that ad through a form inside of the index ads_item views.

and to get clear so that we are on the same page here is a mockup on what I am doing

[Dropbox link image to mockup](https://www.dropbox.com/s/etzq2hfqpzqx4f9/Sk%C3%A4rmklipp%202014-11-20%2012.34.24.png?dl=0)

The error i get is

```
param is missing or the value is empty: ads_item
```

This is what I got

routes

```
  resources :ads_items do
    resources :bookings
  end
```

ads_items controller

```
def new
    @ads_item = AdsItem.new
end

def create
    @ads_item = AdsItem.new(ads_item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ads_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @ads_item, notice: 'Ads item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ads_item }
  else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @ads_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

bookings controller

```
def new

  @booking = Booking.new

end

def create
  @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @booking.save
      format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Model ads_item

```
class AdsItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bookings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bookings
end
```

Model booking

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ads_item
end
```

database

```
create_table "ads_items", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.date     "date"
    t.time     "time"
    t.string   "type_of_service"
    t.string   "address"
    t.text     "include_in_price"
    t.integer  "rate"
    t.integer  "original_price"
    t.integer  "now_price"
    t.boolean  "booked"
    t.string   "category"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "company_information"
    t.string   "company_website"
    t.string   "company_facebook"
    t.string   "company_twitter"
    t.string   "company_instagram"
    t.string   "company_google_maps"
    t.string   "company_phone"
    t.string   "company_name"
    t.string   "logo_path"

end


create_table "bookings", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "social_nr"
    t.string   "phone_nr"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "ads_item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

and the ads_items index view where is list all the items (scaffolded)

```
<% @ads_items.each do |ads_item| %>
   list all items


  <%= form_for :booking do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :social_nr %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone_nr %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.number_field :ads_item_id, :value => ads_item.id %>                          

    <%= f.submit %>


  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I did follow this [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

but it won't work. Am I missing something here ? how do I render the form so that it will get the ads id and save it to the booking table after I filled out the form ?

Comment: So you are trying to create a new Booking and provide a dropdown list of AdsItems in the form? If so, you would just use a select tag: select :ads_item_id, options_from_collection_for_select(AdsItem.all, :id, :type_of_service)

Comment: "belongs_to :ads_item", but ... is not "belongs_to :adsitem" ?

Comment: oh no, I have updated this page so that it will display what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done so far looks correct. You can use the nested attributes feature in rails to create a booking through the AdItem model, have a look at the documentation here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

You would use the fields_for method in your view to render the booking form.

Comment: hmm, now it says "param is missing or the value is empty: ads_item" anything else I am missing here ? @mikhail

Comment: any thoughts on this ? =)

Comment: if you are using strong parameters you need to permit the booking_attributes otherwise you won't have access to them in the controller method

Comment: how do I permit the strong parameters ? Have been struggerling with this problem for 1.5 days now and googeling alot, but no luck here. Any chance on helping me with this problem ?

Comment: Have a look at this guide http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: yes, i know that you need to have accepts_nested_attributes_for it, but it still does not work. I have no clue why